# Input range slider iOS Safari poor performance

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, safari

I have created a simple range slider component for a NextJS application. It uses a `<input type="range">` element.

It works as expected on Desktop and Android but in iOS Safari it is almost unusable. The element does not really move and the updates are very slow.

It is a controlled input since the value must be rendered outside of another element.

```
type Props = {
  onChangeValue: (value: number) => void;
};

export default function RangeSlider({ onChangeValue }: Props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(50);

  const handleChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = ({
    target: { value },
  }) => {
    const newValue = parseInt(value);
    if (typeof newValue !== "number") {
      return;
    }
    setValue(newValue);
    onChangeValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{value}</p> 
      <input
        type="range"
        value={value}
        min={1}
        step={1}
        max={100}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there something I am missing or is this a bug in Safari?
Are there any potential optimizations I can do?
I thought about using a full slider library, but this seems a little bit awkward to me, for such a little input. Can you recommend any small and performant libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be good. I traced the problem to another component (react-spring-bottom-sheet). I replaced it with react-modal-sheet and the problem is gone.